# Nothing Shows Up after no error implementation of Jankuri ng-gallery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gallery

So I referred to this link http://demo.jankuri.com/ngGallery/ to make image gallery.

I did everything as directed but nothing shows up as in no images are shown.

Here is my Controller

```
    var check123 = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        var a = {thumb: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/thumbnails/' + objectidphoto[i], img: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/' + objectidphoto[i]};
        arr.push(a);
    }
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(arr[0]);

}
```

> This is not my complete controller only the significant part.

This is my front end code

```
    <body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    <div class="content">
        <ng-gallery images="MyCtrl.arr"></ng-gallery>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="controller14.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/ngGallery.js"></script>

</body>
```

The angular code executes without any errors and I am getting proper response in return for that console.log(arr).

What am I doing wrong?

> Updated Segment

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['jkuri.gallery']).
   controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $document)
    {
        var self = this;
        self.images = [
            {thumb: 'images/offers/'+'123456789/thumbnails/' + '1445524452873_491676259.jpg', img: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/' + '1445524452873_491676259.jpg'},
            {thumb: 'images/offers/'+'123456789/thumbnails/' + '1445524894340_7a668c73cddcd2050821f83be901832a_1426070017.jpg', img: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/' + '1445524894340_7a668c73cddcd2050821f83be901832a_1426070017.jpg'}

        ];
    });
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
        <ng-gallery images="MyCtrl.images"></ng-gallery>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="controller14.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/ngGallery.js"></script>

</body>
```

Now I have exactly replicated what the module's demo looks like. Still the problem is there. There is no change on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference Myctrl.arr , you do not need to prefix the controller name. Just arr should work, that is, if you're correctly assigning arr to the scope. $scope.arr.push ...

I'm going to take a guess you're doing neither of the above.

UDATED:

Your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['jkuri.gallery']). controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $document) { $scope.images = [ {thumb: 'images/offers/'+'123456789/thumbnails/' + '1445524452873_491676259.jpg', img: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/' + '1445524452873_491676259.jpg'}, {thumb: 'images/offers/'+'123456789/thumbnails/' + '1445524894340_7a668c73cddcd2050821f83be901832a_1426070017.jpg', img: '../images/offers/'+'123456789/' + '1445524894340_7a668c73cddcd2050821f83be901832a_1426070017.jpg'} ]; });
```

Your html

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <div> <ng-gallery images="images"></ng-gallery> </div> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script> <script src="controller14.js"></script> <script src="ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script> <script src="ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/ngGallery.js"></script> </body>
```

Note the $scope assignment and the lack of the controller name.

Comment: Thanks man. The module is full of errors, no arrows or close watermark is visible there + I wish I could add one more button or something.